# SSRS Charts: Issues filtering data from a dataset

Tags: sql, reporting-services, charts, ssrs-2012

I am attempting to create a line (possibly column) chart on an **SSRS** report that compares ticket sale revenue versus TV ad expenses, by week, within 8 weeks of an event. I have attempted to use 2 different data sets, but was never able to get it to work. Instead, I combined both datasets into one with the following columns: 

weeks_out - number of weeks out from event

tickets - total tickets or # of ad spots for TV ads

revenue - total ticket revenue or total ad expenses for week

category - "Ticket Sale" or "TV Cable"

I create the chart using revenue as my series and weeks_out as the Category Groups. If I provide no filters, it would just simply sum the ticket revenue and ad expenses together. I changed the series expression from `SUM(Fields!revenue.Value)` to `IIF(Fields!category.Value = "Ticket Sale", Fields!revenue.Value, 0)`, and it worked just fine displaying weekly ticket revenue without the ad expenses added in. However I tried the following IIF statements to get TV Cable to display and all it would display is 0s for every week:

```
IIF(Fields!category.Value = "TV Cable", Fields!revenue.Value, 0), 
IIF(Fields!category.Value <> "TV Cable", 0, Fields!revenue.Value), 
IIF(Fields!category.Value <> "Ticket Sale", Fields!revenue.Value, 0), 
IIF(Fields!category.Value = "Ticket Sale", 0, Fields!revenue.Value)
```

I have tried displaying the raw data in a table and that worked fine and IIF statement filters worked on it as well. At this point I can't quite figure out what is wrong with my data or the way I am setting up the chart that would make the ticket sales always work but the ad expenses never work on their own.

**Edit**: It appears to be the order that the data is being presented might be causing part of the issue. The query I wrote defaults to display the ticket sales first. I edited the query to display the TV Cable category first. Now when I add a conditional statement, the ad expenses show fine, but the ticket sales will not display by themselves.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to SUM your expression, otherwise you're only seeing the value from the first record.

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!category.Value = "Ticket Sale", 0, Fields!revenue.Value))
```

I tried to just add this as a comment but the commenting (and other things) don't seem to be working.